# I add to my ionic project camera plugin but i recieve an error: object is not a function

Tags: ionic-framework

When I add the camera plugin and run my app i recieve the following error:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Object(...) is not a
>   function TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
>       at Camera.getPicture

Comment: Sometimes this is a version problem , what is your ionic version and plugin version ?

Answer (score 0):

`app.module.ts` add those

```
import { Camera, CameraOptions } from '@ionic-native/camera'; **Ionic 3**

import { Camera, CameraOptions } from '@ionic-native/camera/ngx'; **Ionic 4**

providers: [
   Camera
  ]
```